How to configure webpack to work with mupdf.js in an Electron, T
I was trying to integrate document viewer tabs in an electron app. First I tried using native bindings to create a node addon but the IPC between main and renderer processes along with mutexes was outweighing the fast processing. Now I tried using the wasm version but I get this error during webpack compilation when trying to build:
ERROR in ./node_modules/mupdf/dist/mupdf-wasm.js
114:51-81 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './' in 'D:\vsprojects\Electron\ElectronPDF\node_modules\mupdf\dist' resolve './' in 'D:\vsprojects\Electron\ElectronPDF\node_modules\mupdf\dist'
Parsed request is a directory using description file: D:\vsprojects\Electron\ElectronPDF\node_modules\mupdf\package.json (relative path: ./dist) using description file: D:\vsprojects\Electron\ElectronPDF\node_modules\mupdf\package.json (relative path: ./dist) as directory existing directory D:\vsprojects\Electron\ElectronPDF\node_modules\mupdf\dist using description file: D:\vsprojects\Electron\ElectronPDF\node_modules\mupdf\package.json (relative path: ./dist) using path: D:\vsprojects\Electron\ElectronPDF\node_modules\mupdf\dist\index using description file: D:\vsprojects\Electron\ElectronPDF\node_modules\mupdf\package.json (relative path: ./dist/index)

From here:
if (ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER) {
    scriptDirectory = nodePath.dirname(scriptDirectory) + '/';
} else {
  // EXPORT_ES6 + ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE always requires use of import.meta.url,
  // since there's no way getting the current absolute path of the module when
  // support for that is not available.
  scriptDirectory = require('url').fileURLToPath(new URL('./', import.meta.url));
  // includes trailing slash
}

I would appreciate any direction, thanks.
webpack.config.js
{
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development', // Set this to 'production' for production builds
    entry: './src/renderer/index.tsx',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map', // Use a safer source map option
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.json', '.mjs',],
        alias: {
            './': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/mupdf/dist'),
        },
      
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'postcss-loader',
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.mjs$/,
                include: /node_modules/,
                type: 'javascript/auto'
            },
             {
                test: /mupdf-wasm\.js$/,
                type: 'javascript/esm', // or 'javascript/dynamic'
             },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './public/index.html',
        }),
    ],
    target: 'electron-main',

};

ts.config.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "jsxFactory": "React.createElement",
    "jsxFragmentFactory": "React.Fragment",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "types": [ "node", "react", "react-dom" ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "src"
    ]
  },
  "include": [ "src", "src/main/preload.ts", "src/renderer/wasm/pdf.worker.mjs" ]
}

